# Rails Application Integration with Instagram and Pinterest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, instagram, pinterest

Is their any way to integrate rails app with Instagram and Pinterest like we do in case of facebook. I have to add these social media in my rails application so that my application will be able to authenticate via Instagram or Pinterest. Also I have to post image to these social sites on user's behalf from my application as we do in case of facebook.

Please Reply
Thanks

Comment: checkout https://github.com/ropiku/omniauth-instagram  and https://github.com/jot/omniauth-pinterest/

Comment: Lot of open issues are their in the gem which is required for the authentication.